# Need help about how to control a light sensor

Tags: c#, asp.net

### I'm not asking for the entire solution, I'm just asking the information about where to buy these programmable hardware brands, models etc.

I have searched many websites about the light sensor, many of them came up with information about some cheap gears which has no programmable functionality.

I need to control a light sensor so when strength of illumination reaches a certain level, it will automatically open a sunroof.

But I have no idea about both where to start this project and where to ask the question other than here.

So I am grateful if someone could come up with details of these two hardware (where to buy, types, brands).

Comment: Dear all, please do not down vote my question without any reasons. Otherwise, it's not helpful and no values at all.

Comment: your questions is open ended, subjective, is not about a **specific** programming problem or a software algorithm and it is off-top (it's mostly about hardware !). Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Nacereddine, as I stated in my post, I know this may not be the right place to ask this kind of questions, but I have no ideas about where to ask. So if you know a better place to ask, I'm more than happy to take your suggestion.

Comment: Well, if you want to do it from a scratch (and its not really hard), you could just buy a microcontroller and program that. If you don't want to bother with soldering and designing boards, I would recommend [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/). It's really easy and you can do anything you can imagine with it.

Comment: @NikoDrašković Hi Niko, this is exactly what I want. But it's not C# based. Do you know any such kind of devices which are based on C#? Or do you have any idea about how to use C# code to interact with it? You can put your post in an answer, so I can mark it as an desirable answer. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do you want to start from a scratch?

Then, you could buy a microcontroller, such as [an Atmel AVR](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega8.aspx), in PDIP package, get a [tool to program it](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRISPMKII.aspx), and build the board you need.

This is not as hard as it may sound. You could get a simple schematic on how to set up the power for the board, the rest is just controlling inputs and outputs via the uC (microcontroller) pins.

You can do programming in C++, and Atmel provides an [IDE](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/default.aspx) used to program their uC.

---

### Do you want the basic board pre-made?

Then, the solution I would recommend is [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/).

> Arduino is an open-source electronics prototyping platform based on
>   flexible, easy-to-use hardware and software. It's intended for
>   artists, designers, hobbyists, and anyone interested in creating
>   interactive objects or environments.

There are plenty of easy tutorials on how to set up various sensors and actuators to your Arduino board.

---

### Doing it with C#

I've never done any .NET programming on uC, however I have heard of [.NET Micro Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/net/multiple-platform-support) which is supposedly just that. But you have to bear in mind that .NET is meant for desktop development, and microcontrollers (or embedded devices) are something completely different as what you're really doing is controlling inputs and outputs.

Don't be afraid to use C++, you probably won't need any advanced knowledge to do what you need to do.

### Edit:

Actually, scratch the previous, apparently [Netduino](http://netduino.com/) is like Arduino for .NET. Might be exactly what you need!

Comment: great answer! I have read the Netduino website, it seems that it is more than a device which bridges the C# code and Arduino devices, am I right? Anyway, thank you for your detailed answer :)

Comment: You're going to have to find out for yourself, I only just found out about Netduino :) Have fun!

Comment: I have browsed that website and haven't found any light sensor related topics... you have any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I was going to suggest going with Arduino - it already has what you need ([LEDSensor](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/LEDSensor)), and it is very well established (they have an active forum with *lots* of members). The thing is, for most problems you **don't really need C#** - for the sunroof task you effectively have one `if` testing for illumination, perhaps another one to check if the sunroof is already opened or closed, and a line to give signal on the electormotor output. Maybe if Netduino is similar enough you could adapt the Arduino equivalent code?

Comment: @Nike, I think you are right.But take a look at http://nwazet.com/tsl2561-digital-luminosity-sensor. What do you think?

Comment: Very nice sensor (I like that it has it's own ADC), however since I'm not familiar with Netduino or Nwazet.GO, I suggest that you should first check out how much support there is for these platforms - such as documentation and especially forums with advanced users/experts.

Comment: @Nike, thx for your advice. I'll check them :)